# What was the first RPG podcast?

Tags: history-of-gaming, podcast

What was the first podcast that specifically focused on tabletop RPGs?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podcast) says the term "podcast" was coined in February 2004. If there were any RPG-related radio shows or actual play recordings from before then I would be interested in learning about those, too.

Comment: FWIW podcasts started back in the 80s: before Apple coined the term "podcast" they were just called internet radio, or webcasts, or audio shows. They were made a lot more discoverable though once they collected under the one name and had some major new services debut to support them.

Comment: @doppelgreener Good point; I would love an answer that gave insight to RPG-focused internet radio or audio shows from the 80s or 90s!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With regards to the first online “Actual Play” recording - it was made on the 29th January, 2003 by Paul Maclean of Yog-Sothoth.com. It was a recording from a D&D game of “Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil”, see: https://www.yog-sothoth.com/wiki/index.php/RPGMP3.com

With respect to the first RPG online audio show that I know of, that would be “Mortality Radio” from November 2001. https://www.enworld.org/threads/mortality-radio-celebrate-mortality-nets-2-year-anniversary.68550/

Comment: And with the incorporated comments cleared out; Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Great answer, thank you! The writeup on the Yog-Sothoth wiki was very interesting, like how it was almost accidental. Trying to find out more about the Mortality radio show, I found https://www.enworld.org/threads/mortality-radio-podcasts.305859/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20020222052552/http://www.mortality.net/shoutcast.php Too bad it doesn't look like the episodes have been archived anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

The earliest one I have been able to find is **[RPGMP3.com](https://rpgmp3.com/v5/worlds-largest-dungeon-session-01/)**, with their "World's Largest Dungeon" series that started on **Sep. 24, 2004**. Not too long after the podcast term was coined. And they're still uploading recordings!

In researching this I found some runner-ups:

- [All Games Considered](http://www.agcpodcast.info/2005/05/all-games-considered-may-12-2005.html) started May 17, 2005
- [Dragon's Landing Inn](https://archive.org/details/dragons_landing_inn-podcast_archive/) started July, 2005
- [Have Games, Will Travel](http://www.havegameswilltravel.net/webpage/2005/07) started July 20, 2005
- [Sons of Kryos](https://sonsofkryos.livejournal.com/?skip=80) started Sep. 17, 2005

All of these podcasts have since ended, but *All Games Considered* was the longest running of these, ending on Aug. 02, 2018.

Another one that came up was [The Harping Monkey's Round Table Podcast](https://web.archive.org/web/20070218044319/http://harpingmonkey.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=category&sectionid=6&id=10&Itemid=53), but the earliest episode date I could find for it was [Episode 14](http://www.mefeedia.com/entry/1104316) on Dec 02, 2005. As such, I think it unlikely that Episode 1 was before RPGMP3.com's 2004 release.

Interestingly, it wasn't until 2007 that "Best Podcast" became an award category in the Ennies (it went to *Have Games, Will Travel*).

Answer (score 0):

The 1995 *Kaze to Honō no Majin* (or *Demons of Wind and Flame*) was an adaptation of the second novelization in the *Record of Lodoss War* series (itself based on a D&D campaign), if we're counting audio drama based on novels based on "replay".

Comment: It would be helpful to talk about the format of this production to support this answer. Google indicates that these were released as a set of CDs which, I do not believe meet the generally accepted criteria of what a podcast is.

Comment: If a friend were to invite me to listen to Lodoss and then to listen to The Adventure Zone, I’d be sitting at their computer for both. I could put both of those on my phone. The distinction is mainly in distribution, which admittedly is part of the definition of a podcast.

Comment: This is an interesting bit of history I was not aware of, and is worthy of an "honorable mention" since it's audio and rpg-related. But it's not really what I'm looking for because it's a couple steps removed (based on a novel) and an audio drama rather than a recording of a play session or a discussion about RPGs.